# Recaptcha is not working after enabling JavaScript in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I created a WebView. But, the ReCaptcha isn't working. Some people say, by enabling JavaScript ReCaptcha will work. I enabled JavaScript

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

But still, ReCaptcha isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Add settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

and your final code should be like below

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("url");
```